# Razor variable inside ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have variable for a CSS class value that is assigned to variable in a view:

```
string aboutLinkClass = "normalLink";
```

This can change based on context. Later in the view I call Html.ActionLink and I need to use that variable, but the following fails to produce the desired output:

```
@Html.ActionLink("About", "Index", "about", null, new {@class="@aboutLinkClass"})
```

It treats @aboutLinkClass as static text. so it produces:

```
<a class="@aboutLinkClass" href="/about">About</a>
```

Instead I want it to produce:

```
<a class="normalLink" href="/about">About</a>
```

What is the syntax I need to use to pass it correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("About", "Index", "about", null, new {@class = aboutLinkClass})
```

You're passing the string literal `"@aboutLinkClass"` when you actually want to pass your `String` object called `aboutLinkClass`.

Comment: Perfect -- I was over thinking it with Razor again.